# How to read multiple files from a resource directory

Tags: java, android

Sorry for this question, I'm an amateur programmer.

I have  495 text file in `raw` directory of my project which I want to read. The problem is, I am only able to read one of them with the following code, but I have no idea how to read all files.

please help me,

```
try {
    Resources res = getResources();
    InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.help);

    byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
    in_s.read(b);
    txtHelp.setText(new String(b));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    txtHelp.setText("Error: can't show help.");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read all the Raw resources names
2. Get the actual id (int) and open the Resource as InputStream

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
       String[] names = new String[fields.length];

       // Step 1: Read the names
       for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
           names[i] = fields[i].getName();
       }
       // Step 2: Read as InputStream
       for (int i = 0  ; i < allStringsNames.length ; i++){
           int id = getResources().getIdentifier(names[i] , "raw", getPackageName());
           InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(id);
           //Do your stuff with variable inputStream
       }
       }
   ```